# AttributeError: module 'linecache' has no attribute 'lazycache'

Tags: visual-studio-code, tensorflow2.0

am getting error while running the below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

sentences = [
    'I love my dog',
    'I love my cat'
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words= 100)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
word_index=tokenizer.word_index
print(word_index)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNDoX.png)

Comment: How are you running that token.py? Is it with Python3.7? This happens sometimes when you are running a program with python2 and the package is installed for python3. Also can you please print the content of the `sys.path` variable (`import sys` + `print(sys.path)`)?

Comment: am running python 3.6 and package is for 3.6 still i have the same issue

Comment: In fact, the package as seen in the screenshot you provide is in the ".../python37/..." folder so it seems it is installed for Python 3.7. Anyway, can you please show the content of `sys.path`?

Comment: the above mentioned error has be resolved,now i have new error AttributeError: module 'linecache' has no attribute 'lazycache' kindly help me on this

Comment: What I could see in the documentation is that lazycache is a function of the module. Are you treating it like that (calling as `linceche.lazycache(arg1, arg2)`? But please, kindly edit the post and add some code to it. I cannot help you with just that without knowing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i have update the code

Comment: Sorry I do not know the answer to your problem, maybe someone else is able to help you. However, it may be some version issue, I would try to upgrade de packages using pip with `pip install tensorflow -U` or even upgrading linecache package with the same command